# Issues with JSON formatting for data object in Grafana

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, grafana

Data is not coming in with proper JSON formatting, so I'm having to loop through items in the array to fix the formatting, parsing the changed items and I cannot use the new object(s) when everything is finished because it is no longer in an array. The data is coming in as follows:
data [datapoints: [0..1..]
target: "up{cluster="bluehills_c3260_cluster",component="atr",datacenter="bluehills",hostname="ny-153-177"...}"]
Is there an easier way to convert this using a .map function or some other method to make things cleaner and get the desired result?

I've tried several methods including .replace, .map, and .push. I've also tried JSON.stringify, but nothing else seems to work except what I currently have.

```
onDataReceived(data) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  // Loop through data array
    var txt = data[i].target;  // Create the variable to store the data target
    var j;
    for (j = 0; j <= txt.length; j++) {  // Loop through the data target
      var newObj = txt.slice(2,j);  // Remove "up"
      var filteredObj = newObj  // Change over to JSON format...
      .replace(/=/g,' : ')
      .replace(/,/g,', ')
      .replace(/{/g,'{ ')
      .replace(/cluster/g,'"cluster"')
      .replace(/component/g,'"component"')
      .replace(/datacenter/g,'"datacenter"')
    }
    var dataObj = filteredObj.replace(/_"cluster"/gi,'_cluster');
    var finalObj = JSON.parse(dataObj);
    console.log("finalObj", dataObj);
  }
}
```

What I want is a single array with the proper JSON format for the data (target) coming in.

Comment: What is `data`? `data [datapoints: [0..1..] target: "up{cluster="bluehills_c3260_cluster",component="atr",datacenter="bluehills",hostname="ny-153-177"...}"]` <- This thing looks like a string value to me but your code suggest not. How does the input look like?

Comment: From what I know from experience of developing `Grafana` plugin is that `data` is possibly a list. And it should consists of an array of data points where each item in the array is just another array of length 2. Pos 0 is time Pos 1 is value. 
E.g. `{ datapoints: [ [10000, 20], [20000, 30] ], target: "Blah", somethingElse: {} }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onDataReceived(data){
    this.createCosmo(data);
  }

  createCosmo(data) {

    var arr = $.map(data,function(value){
      return value.target;
    });

    var arr2 = $.map(arr,function(value){
     var newObj = value.slice(2);  // Remove "up"
     var filteredObj = newObj  // Change over to JSON format
         .replace(/=/g,' : ')
         .replace(/,/g,', ')
         .replace(/{/g,'{ ')
         .replace(/cluster/g,'"cluster"')
         .replace(/component/g,'"component"')
         .replace(/datacenter/g,'"datacenter"')
         .replace(/hostname/g,'"hostname"')
         .replace(/instance/g,'"instance"')
         .replace(/job/g,'"job"')
         .replace(/resilience_group/g,'"resilience_group"')
         .replace(/_"cluster"/gi,'_cluster')
         .replace(/-"cluster"/gi,'-cluster');
         var finalObj = JSON.parse(filteredObj);  // Parse the Object into JSON
         return finalObj;
    });

}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I moved the code for processing the data into a new lifecycle hook. I then called that hook within the onDataReceived function and passed the data into the function. Next, I used the $.map() function to run through each piece of the data without breaking the array. I then returned an object that could then be used to pull the values from. The key is the $. (it is necessary in this instance to get the normal functions to work). I hope someone else may benefit from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
const myReg = /([\w\s]+)=\"([^"]*)\"/g
const str = `data [datapoints: [0..1..] target: "up{cluster="bluehills_c3260_cluster",component="atr",datacenter="bluehills",hostname="ny-153-177"...}"]`;
let matches = null;
const resultsJson = {};
while(matches = myReg.exec(str)){
    resultsJson[matches[1]] = matches[2];
}
```

> { cluster: 'bluehills_c3260_cluster',
>     component: 'atr',
>     datacenter: 'bluehills',
>     hostname: 'ny-153-177' }

Not sure if this is how you want to have the data stored but that part would be pretty easy to customize.

Comment: I am not getting anything with this except errors. I think that regEx is not allowed with this particular setup.